# Mathematical description of covariance matrix

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

Using the `nlme` R package, I specified a model of the form

```
model <- lme(Y ~ time * group, random = ~1|A,
             correlation = corGaus(form = ~time|A/B, nugget = TRUE))
```

How would you *mathematically* describe the structure of the covariance matrix of this model?

It is probably somewhat related to [my general question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/382090/serial-correlation-structures-with-two-nested-random-intercepts), but this is more specific and related to R.

I am not sure what it means mathematically, when the random intercepts are different in `random` and `correlation` arguments of the `lme` function. How does this affect the covariance matrix?

Comment: Could you provide some r code to generate a fake dataset, such that I can verify my idea about this question?

Comment: @user158565 Like this?

`A <- factor(c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 8), rep(3, 8)));
    B <- factor(c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4), rep(5, 4), rep(6, 4)));
    group <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4));
    time <- rep(c(1, 2, 7, 14), 6);
    Y <- rnorm(24, 10, 1);
    data <- cbind(A, B, group, time, Y)`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out what `'correlation` means in `lme`.